# GE NetPRO UPS monitoring software available for Windows Server 2008?

Tags: monitoring, hardware, ups, power-supply-unit

We've replaced our old file server with a new one running Windows Server 2008. The UPS we used for the old server is a GE NetPro 1500VA unit. It came with JUMP DataShield monitoring software, which seems to not have been updated since 2005. The most recent update I can find (2.2.0) does not support Windows 2008.

Does anyone know of alternative monitoring software that supports Windows 2008 and is compatible with the GE UPS? Although long power outages are rare here I'd still feel safer if I knew the server would shut down properly when the UPS battery runs low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touch choice #1: You could run a GE supported version of Windows in a small VM, and have it signal the host.

Touch choice #2: If the GE NetPro provides serial signaling in addition to network, it probably wouldn't be too hard to adapt a cable and run the Windows 2008 release of APCUPSD, an open source project.

GE must be slowly backing out of this market, since its web page still sells and advertises both the H/W and S/W but does not support WS2008.

Comment: Thanks! The UPS actually only has serial signalling, no network. There is already a W2K3 install running under Hyper-V on the server. Unfortunately Hyper-V doesn't allow attaching a physical serial port to a virtual machine. I'll have a look to see if I can get it working with ser2net (http://ser2net.sourceforge.net/). If that doesn't work I guess APCUPSD is the final option, although my time would then probably be better spent hacking in support for GE UPSes than building a new serial cable.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but for those still interested, it IS possible to run Datashield in W2K8.
The installer will fail, but if you have a successful installation on another box, simply copy the datashield folder and the shortcuts from the start menu. Then right-click  the shortcut "DataShield", click "Compatibility" and choose  "Windows Server 2003". Edit the files "runshield.bat" and "runshield.ini" and verify the path to "java.exe". Add "C:\DataShield\serial\WinDesk" to your system path (if c:\DataShield is your installation directory that is...).
That's it!